# string IndexOf EOT does not work in net-5 projects

Tags: c#, .net-5

I am upgrading one of the net framework project to net5, observed a change in behavior of a same line of code in net framework vs net5. For example if I have a text wit EOT, net5 doesn't give the index but the same works in net framework project.

```
string sampleString = "hello" + "\u0004" + "test";
string delimiter = "\u0004";
var test = sampleString.IndexOf(delimiter);
\\Net framework gives a index **5**
\\Net core gives a index **0** for the code
```

Any reason for this change in behavior?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# "anyString".Contains('\0', StringComparison.InvariantCulture) returns true in .NET5 but false in older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574888/c-sharp-anystring-contains-0-stringcomparison-invariantculture-returns-tr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
string delimiter = "\u0004";
string sampleString = "hello" + delimiter + "test";

var uniCodeValue = char.Parse(delimiter);//  '\u0004' unicode values
var test = sampleString.IndexOf(uniCodeValue); //5
test = sampleString.IndexOf("test"); //6
```

Comment: Good solution, `char.TryParse` would be good as well.

Comment: This work approach works, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome!