# .NET 6: string.IndexOf returns wrong value when looking for "/" on computers with Thai language

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I'm running this small test program on .NET 6, Windows 11:

```
int x = "event:/SFX/Crackling/CracklingLoop".LastIndexOf("/");
if (x == 20)
    Console.WriteLine("LastIndexOf ok: " + x);
else
    Console.WriteLine("LastIndexOf failed: "+x);

int y= "event:/SFX/Crackling/CracklingLoop".IndexOf("/");
if (y == 6)
    Console.WriteLine("IndexOf ok: " + y);
else
    Console.WriteLine("IndexOf failed: "+y);
```

On my computer, it prints the expected values:

```
LastIndexOf ok: 20
IndexOf ok: 6
```

However, on the computers of some customers, it prints:

```
LastIndexOf failed: 34
IndexOf failed: 0
```

I'm completely baffled how this is possible. When I re-implement string.IndexOf myself, everything works as expected.

There have been changes regarding IndexOf and \n characters (previously discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28218), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64833645/string-indexof-returns-different-value-in-net-5-0) and in other places). However, these strings do not contain any \n.

Comment: Is there any information about the systems your clients are running? Could potentially be an issue between 32/64-bit machines?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

Comment: The results suggest `/` is treated the same as the empty string for purposes of comparing using the culture-specific collation of the user (if it truly *failed*, as in, found nothing, `.IndexOf()` would have returned -1). What does `.IndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal)` give you?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Indeed! Using StringComparison.Ordinal makes it work correctly. The customer where it failed has their Windows set to Thai language. I will use .Ordinal everywhere. Feel free to turn your comment into an answer.