# What is used by default in String.Compare or CompareTo

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how `string.CompareTo(string)` and `String.Compare(string, string)` really work.

I initially wanted to compare "9" and ":" and expected to get negative result because I thought that string comparison was made char by char, using ASCII code/Unicode. (so '9' would have been 57 and ':' is 58)

But the result is 1, so "9" is after ":"?

```
  string s1 = ('7').ToString();
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
      string s2 = ( (char)((int)'6' + i) ).ToString();
      Console.WriteLine($"s1 '{s1}' & s2 '{s2}' \t--> s1.CompareTo(s2) : {s1.CompareTo(s2)} \tand String.Compare(s1, s2) : {String.Compare(s1,s2)} \n");
  }
```

Output:

```
s1 '7' & s2 '6'     --> s1.CompareTo(s2) : 1      and String.Compare(s1, s2) : 1    
s1 '7' & s2 '7'     --> s1.CompareTo(s2) : 0      and String.Compare(s1, s2) : 0    
s1 '7' & s2 '8'     --> s1.CompareTo(s2) : -1     and String.Compare(s1, s2) : -1    
s1 '7' & s2 '9'     --> s1.CompareTo(s2) : -1     and String.Compare(s1, s2) : -1    
s1 '7' & s2 ':'     --> s1.CompareTo(s2) : 1      and String.Compare(s1, s2) : 1    
s1 '7' & s2 ';'     --> s1.CompareTo(s2) : 1      and String.Compare(s1, s2) : 1
```

I ran some more tests, and discovered than "W" is between "w" and "x".

[image: w < W < x]

How are chars sorted by default?

Adding `StringComparison.Ordinal` in `String.Compare(s1, s2)` finally gave me the result I initially wanted (don't care about the value, just the sign matters for me) but I'm still confused by the default behaviour.

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus.md#default-search-and-comparison-types) you can find a list about the default comparers for the individual APIs. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64833645/5114784) is a related question, which demonstrates the possible consequences of omitting the comparer. This was the breaking change introduced in .NET 5 that @OlivierJacot-Descombes mentioned in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

No need to figure out how things work, its all documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-8.0#system-string-compare(system-string-system-string)

and you can even find the source code for the functin here:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,b42f029a93d6432a

Comment: I understand that result will change depending on my CultureInfo, but how can I have details on how my CultureInfo (or even InvariantCulture) sort chars? –

Comment: if you follow the second link you can go down in the source code and see if for yourself and you ll end up here, finding your answer:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8711fff131bc4d0e

Comment: You may also follow the links in the article [Behavior changes when comparing strings on .NET 5+](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus.md).

Comment: @Twibby thats way more complicated then pointing at an algorithm when leaving the space of ordinal comparisons. Its either handled by the OS (Windows NLS) or if you are on Net Core by the ICU libraries that are deployed on the system where your code will run. Both NLS & ICU have a "complicated" rulesets for every Culture that is beyond simply bytes/char comparison by some encoding system. And as always both systems a versioned and behavior may change by version.