C# string.IndexOf differs across environments
I am getting strange results for string.IndexOf in some environments (unfortunately, I do not have direct access to the machine to obtain details). But the behavior is similar what I can simulate here:
    var testString = "STX";
    var iof = testString.IndexOf('\u20BD'.ToString(), 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine($"IOF: {iof}");

With Roslyn 4.8 the output is 0, what is unexpected for me:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZX3s2z
However, for .NET7 the output is as expected -1:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/7mvKuP
What I was able to get from the target machine, the FrameworkDescription is  Framework description .NET 7.0.0-rc.2.22472.3 and there the code returns 0 instead of -1.
Can it be related to the RC version and the .NET runtime update would resolve it?

This is almost certainly the switch from NLS to ICU: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

Perhaps you meant StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9760339/14868997

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus#behavioral-differences

Semi-duplicate (StringComparison is implicitly current culture there but the reason is the same): https://stackoverflow.com/q/64833645/5114784
